# what tools do you use to debug your asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, debugging

this is acutally one of the interview questions I had. I didnt really use any tools to debug, only use trace, debug, breakpoint, command window.

I dont think my answer is what they are looking for.  please tell me what tools do you use to debug your asp.net application  and how do you debug the applicaiton in both Dev and Production environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Visual Studio is the most powerful debugger in the world, but mostly limited to server-side code.
- Firebug, or the built-in dev tools in Chrome and IE for JavaScript
- Fiddler for examining web requests, AJAX, etc.
- SQL Server Profiler to find SQL-to-ASP discrepancies, query timing, etc
- Red Gate tools for memory profiling, finding leaks.  VS also has good profiling tools, depending on what version you're using.

Comment: Add Remote Debugger for prod debugging (you really should try to replicate prod issues in staging)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the dot net developers are using Visual studio debugger for all dot net applications such as ASP.NET, VB.NET, Console applications.

For ASP.NET application, you can debug server side & client side codes from VS (when you are running the application from VS). It will be in DEV & Prod environment you can use the latest DLL and attach debugger mode and test it in VS.

For Client side, you can use firebug in firefox, dev tools in Chrome and IE for JavaScript.
For more details please [see this link.](http://www.techieclues.com/dot-net-pgming/dot-net-pgming.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well it really depends on what you are debugging?

I often use Fiddler for trafic debugging and IE Deveoper Tools or Firefox Firebug for css, html and sometimes javascript debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Debug, Firebug for Firefox with Firecookie addon, IE Developer tools and SQL Profiler for starters.